# Given a list of rectangle coordinates, how can we find all possible combinations of polygons from these coordinates?

Tags: math, image-processing, computer-vision, geometry

Given the following list of region coordinates:

```
x   y   Width   Height
1   1   65  62
1   59  66  87
1   139 78  114
1   218 100 122
1   311 126 84
1   366 99  67
1   402 102 99
7   110 145 99
```

I wish to identify all possible rectangle combinations that can be formed by combining any two or more of the above rectangles. For instance, one rectangle could be

```
1 1 66 146 by combining 1   1   65  62 and 1    59  66  87
```

What would be the most efficient way to find all possible combinations of rectangles using this list?

Okay. I'm sorry for not being specific about the problem. 
I have been working on an algorithm for object detection that identifies different windows across the image that might have the object. But sometimes, the object gets divided into several windows. So, when looking for objects, I want to use all the windows that I identified as well as try their different combinations for object detection.

So far I have tried using 2 loops and going across all the windows one by one
: If the x coordinate of the second loop window lies in the first loop window, then I merge those two by taking the left-most, top-most, right-most and bottom-most coordinates.

However, this has been taking a lot of time and there are a lot of duplicates present in the final output. I would like to see if there is a more efficient and easier way to do this.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: How many rectangles are there, generally, in the input lists? Also, how frequently are you running this code (60 FPS?)

Comment: @templatetypedef The rectangles usually range from 50 till 60. And the frequency would be around 30fps.

Comment: With those numbers, I'm actually a little surprised that a simple double-for loop isn't fast enough. 60 rectangles makes for 1770 pairs of rectangles. Let's say it takes ten microseconds to process a single pair of rectangles (which I'd say would be pretty high; that's around 10,000 clock cycles). That still would let you run at 30fps with some room to space. Can you post the exact code that you're using? I suspect there might be something else going on here.